# Get a dictionary of a generic type based on a runtime value

Tags: c#, .net, types, reflection

I wish to declare a dictionary based on a runtime type. So, instead of doing this:

```cs
IEnumerable dict = null;
if(type == typeof(SomeType)) dict = new Dictionary<SomeType, string>()
if(type == typeof(SomeOtherType)) dict = new Dictionary<SomeOtherType, string>()
```

I wish to do something like this:

```cs
IEnumerable dict = new Dictionary<type, string>();
```

How can I achieve this? Also, I would like to be able to call a different method with just the type of the dictionary in one of these ways:

```cs
var result = SomeMethod(typeof(Dictionary<type, string>));
```

```cs
var result = SomeMethod<Dictionary<type, string>>();
```

EDIT:
extra context:

I get the types from a different API call as strings. Then I use reflection to get the types by AssemblyQualifiedName, which results in a List to execute the calls with. Based on the name of these types, REST endpoints need to be called.

```cs
If (type == SomeType) httpClient.GetAsync("SomePath/{SomeType.Name}")
```

This endpoint returns a Dictionary<SomeType, string>. To be able to deserialize these types, I need to call something like

```cs
httpClient.GetAsync<Dictionary<type, string>>("SomePath/{SomeType.Name}")
```

Otherwise an exception will occur in the System.Text.Json package.

Comment: Why can't you use `Dictionary<object, string>`?

Comment: @shingo I was using `Dictionary<InterfaceThatAllRelevantTypesImplement, string>`, but need to do some things with the HttpClient and deserialization which need a hard type to correctly deserialize into that dict.

Comment: Do you *definitely* not need it in a strongly-typed way at compile-time after creating it? (It would really help if you could provide more context in the question.)

Comment: *"How can I achieve this?"*. You can't. That's not how generics work. You need to know the generic type parameters at compile time. If you didn't, how could the compiler possibly guarantee type safety?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: If you don't *need* that safety, it's fine. See my answer. Everything *actually asked for* in the question can be done easily enough. Whether that will actually be sufficient what the OP wants is a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have some types that are not known at compiletime and based on the name of these types, REST endpoints need to be called. If type == SomeType: `httpClient.GetAsync("SomePath/SomeType")`. This endpoint returns a `Dictionary<SomeType, string>`.

Comment: That looks like you do know at compile time what the types are, generics seem to be a good fit here, but again without more context, it's hard to suggest an option.

Comment: @DavidG I do not. I get the types from a different API call as strings. Then I use reflection to get the types by AssemblyQualifiedName, which results in a List<Type> to execute the calls with.

Comment: @StijnWingens: Please put the context *in  the question*... although that extra context doesn't sound like what you've already got in the question at all, which makes it even more important to provide context.

Comment: The endpoint can only return binary data, and it is up to you to deserialize it. The question is, do you first need to create an instance of `SomeType` when deserializing, or do you already have a deserialization library that requires a `Dictionary<SomeType, string>`?

Comment: Note that most deserializers accept a `Type` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you genuinely don't care about the type at compile-time, you just want to create an instance, you can do that with reflection easily:

```cs
var dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(string));
var dictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(dictionaryType);
```

The `dictionaryType` construction above would also let you call:

```cs
var result = SomeMethod(dictionaryType);
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks! I've still got some issues around deserialization but the type is at least used correctly. Any tips on deserializing json into a dictionary of runtime types?

Comment: @StijnWingens: No, please ask a new question with *all* the relevant context. (I have no idea what you even mean, and even if it *was* clear, it would be inappropriate to ask follow-up questions in comments.)